# CodeIgniter 2.1 + Sparks + hmvc(latest) cannot load libraries/sparks

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

Anytime i attempt to load sparks i cant load the libraries, Its almost as if HMVC has broken the loading of sparks.

#### An example:

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Index extends MX_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->spark('template/1.9.0');
        $this->load->library('template');       
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->template
             ->title('TSET123')
             ->build('index/index');
    }
}
```

**causes:**  `Unable to load the requested class: template`

i have attempted following these instructions over @ getsparks.org: http://getsparks.org/set-up-mx

but its still not working, any ideas?

#### Using:

- HMVC Latest
- CI 2.1.x (tried 1.0 and 1.1)
- Latest Sparks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to make (assets and template) sparks library to work with HMVC, but be sure that other spark libraries will not work as it should ( since i also tried ion_auth and it didnt work ).

1. first of all you have to have a fresh HMVC installation  then you
2. will have to install sparks but dont overwrite the MX loader nor the MX module files
3. get the `MY_Loader` file from sparks  extend it from `MX_Loader` not from `CI_Loader` like this:

`require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php";`

```
class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {
/*the MY_Loader code from getsparks.org*/}
```

you may like this simple code http://s.zah.me/IE0BQ4

Answer (score 1):

After following all the steps described at http://getsparks.org/set-up-mx

Go to application/third_party/MX/Modules.php 
and change :-

```
define('SPARKPATH', APPPATH.'sparks/');
```

to

```
define('SPARKPATH', FCPATH.'sparks/');
```

OR

you can place your sparks folder inside applications directory

With this change, ion_auth and oauth2 sparks should work as well

Answer (score 0):

From the sample code

```
$this->load->spark('example-spark/1.0.0'); 
$this->example_spark->method();
```

I don't see any of sample like this ...

```
$this->load->library('something load via spark');
```

In your case should be ...

```
$this->template->some_method();
```

Comment: its there, just not in the sample code provided, ill update it.. thats not the issue.